# Is there a way to iterate through a nested list's items and produce another nested list in Python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code translates a nested list of characters to unicode.

```
 LetterList=[["a", "b", "c","d"],["e","f","g"]]

 ArrayTranslate=[]

 def Encode(Array):
    for List in Array:
        for letter in List:
            if isinstance(letter,int)==False:
               ArrayTranslate.append(ord(letter))
            elif isinstance(letter,int)==True:
               ArrayTransLate.append(letter)
Encode(LetterList)

print(ArrayTranslate)
```

When I run the program I produce list as follows

```
[97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103]
```

However I want to produce a nested list of these values as follows:
    [[97,98,99,100],[101,102,103]]
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or if what I'm trying to achieve is possible

Answer (score 1):

You code isn't working because you appending the results to the one list and you getting at the final only one list with your values. 
You could do it with nested [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

```
In [69]: LetterList
Out[69]: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 'f', 'g']]

In [70]: [[ord(i) if not isinstance(i, int) else i for i in l] for l in LetterList]
Out[70]: [[97, 98, 99, 100], [1, 102, 103]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue

```
LetterList=[["a", "b", "c","d"],["e","f","g"]]


Encode=[[ord(letter) for letter in List] for List in LetterList]
print(Encode)
```

Which gives:

```
 [[97, 98, 99, 100], [101, 102, 103]]
```

Comment: It will not work if you'll have `int` in your `LetterList` try my edited answer

Comment: Thank you, I didn't consider integers